# What can I put on these bricks that are sticking up to get them flush again?

Tags: brick

The house I just moved into has bricks laid in a pattern of stright columns the bricks are sitting tight but 1 inch is sticking up. Everyone stubs their toe on them. The area is about 7 feet long and about 5 feet wide. Everywhere else around the house the bricks are flush with the ground. What can I put on these bricks that are sticking up to get them flush again?

Comment: A photo would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [*dead blow* hammer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_blow_hammer) and see if you can pound it into the ground further, or pull the high ones out and dig out the underlayment that is preventing it from sitting flush.

Comment: Dead blow hammer on 35 square feet of bricks?  How big is your dead blow hammer?

Comment: This is a patio we're talking about, correct? Dead blow hammer and a piece of 2x4 that spans 3 courses is a great brick leveller. Doesn't work if the bricks are being kicked up by tree roots. It's either use the deadblow or take up the whole field and take care of the problem by putting down a proper layer of compacted gravel and sand.

Comment: Not saying this won't work but I just have never seen it.  Why the dead blow hammer?  If you are doing multiple bricks with board then why not a sledge hammer or whatever.

Comment: Deadblow doesn't bounce, all the force goes into what you're smacking. Soft face doesn't mar stuff. Heavy weight in a small size. 4lb sledge and a board will do just fine. 4lb direct on bricks makes pretty marks and fractures.